# Acciones en el Admin Django me generan error. Verificación CSRF fallida. Solicitud abortada

Tags: django, django-admin

Estoy tratando de crear un usuario desde el administrador de Django pero me esta generando el siguiente error

[image: > Verificación CSRF fallida. Solicitud abortada]

No he modificado el template original del administrador de Django.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar. Gracias